# Set up git bash to work with tabs on windows

Tags: git-bash, console2

I have installed console2 and git bash, 
my goal is to make git bash working with tabs , 
I have changed the target path on console setting to 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`.
When I open console it doesn't give me option for tabs anymore.

Answer (score 101):

I've got this working with ConEmu instead.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/

1. Install Git Bash
2. Install ConEmu
3. Open ConEmu, in settings (top right corner), click "settings"
4. In the settings tree, open "startup", then "tasks"
5. Add a new task, or edit one of the existing ones

   - click on the "tab" button in second row from bottom
   - in the first box, enter "[git directory]\bin\sh.exe --login -s"
   - in the second box, enter your preferred startup directory
   - save
   - now assign a hotkey (top right corner) (I have mine on ctrl+T)
6. You're done! Now you have a multitabbed console in windows, where you can create any number of Git Bash windows via a hotkey.

Comment: Amazing work. Thank you very much for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Hi. As I write this ConEmu already has a git bash task ready to roll. There's no need to edit or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks! ConEmu is awesome!

Comment: You barely even notice you're on Windows any more ;-)

Comment: Conemu shells getting stuck every 5 minutes or so. Also, the most important keyboard shortcut for switching tabs is not configurable. Will need to keep searching...

Answer (score 48):

This config works for me in Console2:

Title: Git Bash

Icon: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico

Shell: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"

Startup dir: the path to your git repo

[image: Console2 settings Git Bash]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. My console2 setup was working fine until I updated to Git 2.7.0, and all the new tabs started opening in new windows. This solved it!

Comment: Thanks.  I also upgraded to Git 2.x and Console2 was effectively broken.  Changing to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c "C:\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i"` (from `C:\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i`) fixed it for me.

Comment: for git 2.x, the icon path is :    Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico

Comment: `Console2` has been renamed to `ConsoleZ` and the source code are moved to github. The repository site is https://github.com/cbucher/console

Comment: This worked for me. Here is the shell location I used (for Git 2.9+ on 64-bit OS): `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"` And the new icon location is: `"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico"`

Comment: What program is this?

Comment: I've added the software name to the answer, since it's not clear from the question title/Google result that this is Console2 (/ConsoleZ) specific.

Answer (score 15):

1. Install Git Bash -> Git for Windows v2.9.3
2. Install ConEMU Version 10.0.17134.48 -->https://conemu.github.io/en/Downloads.html
3. ConEMU latest version comes preconfigured with gitbash and windows cmd. **No settings are required to be done**
4. Open ConEMU
5. Open windows cmd with new console dialog option -> {Shells::cmd} in ConEMU
6. Open git bash with new console dialog option -> {Bash::Git bash} in ConEMU

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution for [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701):

1. Open Settings (`Ctrl + ,`)
2. Add this to the `profiles` property (remember to add a comma after the `{...}` before it):

```
    "profiles":
    {
        ...
        "list":
        [
            ...
            {
                "commandline": "C:\\path\\to\\git\\bin\\bash.exe --login -i",
                "hidden": false,
                "icon": "C:\\path\\to\\git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
                "name": "Git Bash",
                "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%"
            }
        ]
    },
```

3. (Optional) If you want Git Bash to be the default shell when you start Windows Terminal, then add this to the settings:

```
"defaultProfile": "Git Bash",
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know `defaultProfile` takes `name` in place of `guid` too; tried and it works! Upvoted for that tip...

Comment: That didn't work for me, Git Bash just opens its own instance, not appending to the Windows Terminal tabs. Does it work differently for you?

Comment: nice! worked for me.
I initially got same result as @OfirD but after editing via "Open JSON File", it worked as described.  Now i have multi-tabbed git bash! (y)

Comment: @birch, mind sharing your json?

Comment: @OfirD, i don't know how to add as code in comment.
anyway, i just copied the one above changing \\path\\to\\git\\ to my actual path-to-git.

Note that in commandline, bash.exe is used and NOT git-bash.
git-bash will open an instance outside of Terminal.

Comment: Remember to add the guid key.

Comment: I actually found that in the settings I could already configure the Windows Terminal so that each time I click on the + symbol I'd get a Git Bash shell. I didn't have any configuration to do for it somehow.

Answer (score 7):

**Using VSCode IDE**

You can use multiple GIT Bash tabs inside VSCode, if you use it as IDE.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> to open the terminal. You will se a dropdown to the right where you can select bash as default shell if you have GIT Bash installed. You can then use multiple tabs within VSCode.

Comment: Sounds good, except that I have GIT Bash installed and it does not appear in that dropdown menu. I only see powershell.

Comment: The extra steps here work for me though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527994/1447953

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

### Powershell

Console2 works with powershell.  Go to Edit => Settings => Tabs => Add tab => Set Shell to : `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and set Title to "Powershell".  After installing git bash, powershell should work without further configuration.

### ConEmu

I found [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/)'s setup window difficult to work with.  I gave up on setting a default directory.  I use this setup:

[image: ConEmu screen shot]

Be careful about clicking buttons in ConEmu.  It will overwrite whatever you put in command and the buttons add boilerplate code that does not seem to work whatsoever with Git shell.

Comment: To set default directory I resolved using the following command:
"%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:d:C:\mydefault\dir

Comment: Powershell may support Git commands, but it doesn't offer a solution for running Git Bash. Basically, I am having trouble using Powershell to run an instance of Git Bash. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should change Shell. I think you changed Startup Directory.

[image: Shell settings in Console2]

Comment: This did not work for me.  It continues to use powershell no matter what I specify as the shell.

Comment: I used [these settings](http://code.logos.com/blog/2011/06/git_bash_in_console2.html) and it worked for me

Comment: This opens git bash in a "new window", not within Console 2 itself (on Windows 10 Pro).

Answer (score 1):

ConEmu works perfect, thanks for the pre answers.

I download the newest version, seems the support **Git Bash** and **Cygwin** originally. BTW, The shortcut to create a new tab is Win+W, the swith tab shortcut is Ctrl+Tab and Shift+Ctrl+Tab

[image]