# Bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my site with EB CLI. Whenever I try to run $ eb --version, it always shows the error below, even though it works on my CMD. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you.

```
     /c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/eb: 
     c:\users\user: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try double backslash:

```
C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\Scripts\\eb
```

I was facing the same problem in ellipse, backslash and running the code in Python IDLE solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks alot mate! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

This error is related to your terminal and the environment it runs on. You get the same error with e.g. cygwin using git bash. In a script I had something like this:

```
#!/c/Program Files/some_program/executable.exe
```

Escaping the space with a backslash or using quotes didn't work.

The solution is to use the [DOS' short filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename):

- Progra~1 for "Program Files"
- Progra~2 for "Program Files (x86)"

So my line would turn into:

```
#!/c/Progra~1/some_program/executable.exe
```

Comment: I faced this issue for pyang and your solution did the trick. thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

In windows, it works for me using `eb.exe` instead of simply `eb`.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me. I tried double-backslash. It seems that the 'eb' script is using the System or User paths to call other scripts. Even if I manually edit my System and User PATH variables in Windows to use quotes around each entry, I still hit the above issue.

My error:

```
$ /c/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/Scripts/eb -version
  bash: /c/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/Scripts/eb: 
  c:\program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be an issue with EB running on Bash.

So instead I made Visual Studio Code use cmd prompt instead of bash, using the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527994/277601