# Running the Linux Subsystem from Visual Studio's Post-Build Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run the Windows 10 Linux Subsystem from Visual Studio 2015's Post-Build Command Line. That is, I have a command, whose output will be piped to `bash`, for example `xyz | bash`. `bash` should in turn start the Windows 10 Linux Subsystem and execute the command.

This works perfectly when running the command from the regular `CMD.exe` Command Line or `.bat` files. However, when running this from the Visual Studio 2015 Post-, Pre-Build- or Pre-Link-Event Command Line **directly**, via a `call cmd /C` **call** or an external `.bat` file as **proxy**, this fails with error code `255` and prints something like "Command '`bash`' not found.". When trying to use the complete path to the `bash.exe` this fails, too.

How can I run `bash` from Visual Studio's Command Line?

Sidenote: I am trying to run this on a C/C++ Project.

Comment: I believe this post answers your question I don't quite understand your question but I use bash through visual code all the time and this is what I followed to do it. [Bash on Windows from Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-to-use-bash-on-windows-from-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal)

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you can _accept_ answers on Stack Overflow? 

Comment: @m93a Oh, sorry, I forgot about this question since solving this just caused a different problem...

Comment: What problem? If it's bash-related, maybe I could help.

Comment: @m93a Not directly... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126688/unicodeencodeerror-with-visual-studio-post-build-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this problem too when using `bash` from my 32-bit C++ application.

The thing is that `bash` is 64-bit only – when you try to use it from a 32-bit app, your call to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` gets redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bash.exe` which does not exist.

To bypass the redirect you have to use `C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe` when calling bash from a 32-bit app. I actually made a batch (`.bat`) proxy that I added to the `PATH` to make things easier.

`bash.bat:`

```
@echo off

if exist "C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe" (
  C:\Windows\Sysnative\bash.exe %*
) else (
  C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe %*
)
```