# UnicodeEncodeError with Visual Studio Post-Build Command Line

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, cmd, python-3.6, post-build-event

I am trying to run a Python script from a Visual Studio C/C++ project's Post-Build Command Line. The arguments for the script contain German Umlauts, let's say **Ü**. The Command Line Script is

```
python "<path to python .py>" Ü
```

The Python script simply prints the first (second) argument back to the Command Line:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

However, this raises an exception for the last line:

> ...
>
> File "C:\Python36\lib\encoding\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>
> ```
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input, self.errors, encoding_table)[0]
> ```
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2584' in position 0: character maps to < undefined >

How to solve this?

Comment: The difficulties of setting up correct output encoding are well known, just search for the error message and you should be able to locate a few hints how to solve this.

Comment: Do you really use Python 3.6? It shouldn't give this error anymore. Make sure to check the version carefully!

Comment: Yes, this is Python 3.6.1. I added some text from the error message.

Comment: Have you tried `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` or `print u"üäö".encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: In the command, can you examine the hex value of the character? Is this a 0x9A from codepage 437 or a 0xDC from codepage 1252?