# bash: npm: command not found after downloading Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I uninstalled Node.js and reinstalled it to fixed a different error.Now In visual studio terminal for bash and cmd, I am getting

```
bash: npm: command not found.
```

Comment: Maybe with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the address of file where your nodejs is stored and then go to Enviroment variables advance setting select "path" from upper window list,

[image]

then click edit
and then add a ";" in given path then paste the copied address of the nodejs file

Now you can run npm from anywhere !

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and Reinstall fixed it