# Visual Studio Code Pylance (report Missing Imports )

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I keep getting error "X" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [ln 1, Col8]

I AM in fact a beginner, the basic youtube "fixes" are NOT working

- View Command Pallet ... NOT working
- Terminal pip install .... NOT working
  I am running the Zip install on my work computer and im guessing it has something to do with a directory. but i cant seem to figure it out. the bottom left corner shows the python version which is ( Pyhton 3.110a7 64-bit(windows store)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, you may have more than one python installed, have you selected the right one for your project? In the footer of VSCode the version of python it thinks you are using will be displayed. Click that and a drop down will appear from the selection box in the top bar of the code window, select the appropriate python and then wait a few minutes for it to scan your code and find all of your imports.

Answer (score 49):

Pylance requires you to set the Python PATH:

If you're in Mac/linux, make use of :

```
which python3
```

And in windows:

```
where python
```

So that the path in which you're python is installed is returned

Copy that path.

Go to your vscode and open the settings.json file (CTRL + SHIFT + P, and type "settings.json" at search bar)

Add the following key to the json file

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/YOURUSERNAME/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3"
```

This was just an example, the PATH could be something more like
"C:/users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda3/bin/python3" in case you're using windows.

The following documentation from python for vscode provides more information about how to configure Python for Visual Studio Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference

Comment: This was a huge help and solved my issue perfectly. One minor note is that "where python" didn't work for me on windows and instead I had to run 

import sys;
locate_python = sys.exec_prefix;
print(locate_python)

in the interpreter to find the python location.

Comment: This fixed it for using venv in macos despite activating my using source env_name/bin/activate

Comment: This works perfectly in VSCode ... now also a working version for VS Studio would be helpful in addition.

Comment: This setting is reported as no longer relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Setting-descriptions#pythondefaultinterpreterpath
But I'm still seeing this problem, in particular when importing our namespace packages.

Comment: This worked for me, as well as adding all of my other python installation with "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["PATH1", "PATH2"]

Answer (score 9):

Also, on some occasions, you might have configured your environment by adding custom paths that Pylance can not detect.

In that case, you can use the `python.analysis.extraPaths` parameter to add more paths to your project, such as :

`"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["app", "another/path/etc"]`

(Source: https://dev.to/climentea/how-to-solve-pylance-missing-imports-in-vscode-359b)

Answer (score 8):

There’s a very comprehensive discussion on settings in VS Code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211678/5709144.

In summary and with regard to this specific case, it’s better to change settings by going to (on a Mac) `Code > Preferences > Settings`.

Enter `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in the search box at the top of screen. The current path is shown in an editable text box.

Enter any path you like here - `foobar`, `mother`, whatever you like. It doesn’t matter as, if the path isn’t recognised by VS Code, VS Code lists those that are. The only reason you enter the path is to get the list of potential paths. Click on one of these accepted paths and you’re all set up.

Answer (score 8):

### Disable missing imports reporting at project level:

As asked, your question doesn't specify whether or not your imported module is correctly installed. If it isn't, then this answer will not apply. However, if your code works as expected and you're getting a false warning, then you can ignore the warning by doing the following.

Create the file `.vscode/settings.json` in your current directory and then add the following:

```json
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none",
}
```

Be warned however that this will ignore *all* missing import warnings, not just the one you're trying to get rid of. Therefore, if you have any imports that are *legitimately* missing, the warning will not be there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the VS, Please go to the settings .. search for Advance path and then ADD it (/.source) it should solve the problem.

Hope you have installed the Pylance in your system correctly.

Comment: The best solution, but need to be in ´Python › Analysis: Extra Paths´

Answer (score 3):

To anyone with a missing imports issue. If you have installed Pylance and Python extensions from VS Code, you should hover your mouse over the missing imports. Then, Pylance will show you an option saying *Quick Fix*, click on that and select the right interpreter from the pop-up. After that, I don't see any line under any imports, and autocompletion is working fine. Previously, autocompletion was not working for the missing imports.

Comment: Interesting. Why is the even needed I wonder? If you dev install something and import works ... pylance is ignoring this path?

Comment: I am not aware of the exact reason, but I often face that situation. I think it activates my default Python interpreter for VS code. To change that, I think I might have to mess with the settings of my VS code.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'm editing the .py file over SFTP, and my local don't have those required library, you can click [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [P], and search for Open Workspaces Settings (JSON), and here's my setting for your reference

```json
{
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingImports": "none",
        "reportMissingModuleSource": "none"
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference

Answer (score 1):

Many of the solutions found were not effective fx.`"python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true`.

It worked to create a `settings.json` file within the workspace - CTRL+SHIFT+P and search for Preferences: Open Workspace Settings(JSON). A new folder .vscode is created to store the new settings of such specific workspace.

There, you insert the extraPath `"python.analysis.extraPaths": [".venv/projectfolder/src"]`

In my case, I have placed the project folder within the virtual environment and I have a source folder `src`, where it is present a `main.py` with which I run my script and the pylance import errors were reported

Comment: This is the way. In my case (Mac with homebrew python, OG virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv) the path was `"/Users/airstrike/.virtualenvs/NAMEOFVENVGOESHERE/lib/python3.11/site-packages"`

Answer (score 0):

In summary and with regard to this specific case, it’s better to change settings by going to (on a Mac) `Code > Preferences > Settings`.

Enter `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in the search box at the top of screen.
The current path is shown in an editable text box.
Enter *Python3*

Next scroll down and find **Python> Analysis: import format** and check *Relative*
its my be help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had created a virtual env one directory above the project. Just make it in the same directory and restart the virtual studio code and activate the environment.
*make sure to install the package again.

Worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was quite simple, similarly to Samuel Chan's answer: go to `Code > Preferences > Settings`.

In the top menu, choose your workspace (you can leave it as "User" to apply the change at the user-level).

Then `Extensions > Pylance`.

Scroll down to `Python > Analysis: Diagnostic Severity Overrides`.

Click on "Edit in settings.json". The file opens and suggests a dropdown menu.

Select "reportMissingImports" then "none".

The settings.json now looks like:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingImports": "none"
    }
}
```

Save it and you're done.

Answer (score -2):

At the bottom-right corner of VS Code:

[image: down right corner of VScode]

Just switch on these TypeChecking braces.