# Import Error in Visual Studio Code Despite Extensive Troubleshooting(Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Edit: Solved, I had to create a virtual environment apparently. After I created one and started working from there, importing worked fine.

I've encountered a persistent issue in Visual Studio Code (VSC) where I'm experiencing import errors when trying to import one Python file into another. The error is indicated by a yellow underline beneath the import statement, and the Problems tab states: "Import File could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)". The peculiar thing is, the same code runs perfectly fine in PyCharm, which suggests that this issue is specific to VSC or its extensions.

I have a simple project structure with two Python files in the same directory:

file1.py

```py
import file2
file2.my_function()
```

file2.py

```py
def my_function():
    print("Hallo aus file2!")
```

Example Test File:

test_file.py

```py
import file2

def test_my_function():
    assert file2.my_function() == "Hallo aus file2!"
```

The issue appeared mid-coding session; previously working imports suddenly started showing the error.
The file paths are "C:\Users[username]\import_test\file1.py" and "C:\Users[username]\import_test\file2.py".
The issue persists even with a fresh installation of Python and VSC, and with all Python-related folders deleted.
The code runs without any import errors in PyCharm.
The import statement works to import a function or class, but it is labeled as a defect import, and pytest does not detect it unless it is testing right out of the file.

### Steps Taken:

- Ensured that there are no spaces or special characters in file and folder names.
- Ensured the correct Python interpreter is selected in VSC. Even tried using the Python interpreter from PyCharm in VSC.
- Verified that the Python extension is installed and enabled.
- Only the Python extension is enabled.
- Tried modifying sys.path to include the directory containing the Python files.
- Checked and confirmed both Python files are set to UTF-8.
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled both Python and VSC, ensuring all configuration files and settings were cleared.
- Changed the Python Language Server to Jedi in the settings.json file, and back after it became appearant it didnt cause the issue
- Compared the current working directories in different environments using os.getcwd() to ensure they are the same.
- Cleared Cache and Extension Data
- Added an init.py file to the directory, with no result.
- Tried using relative import from .file2 import my_function, with no result.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled pytest, with no result.

Comment: A pylance error is not a Python error. Pylance can't create errors, it's just a static checker; static checkers are wrong sometimes. That's fine to be an on-topic question here, but the title should make it clear you're talking about a pylance error, not a Python error (which is to say, an actual ImportError).

Comment: Also, the list of things you tried doesn't include setting an explicit `defaultInterpreterPath`, as [Visual Studio Code: pylance report missing imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71918703/visual-studio-code-pylance-report-missing-imports) instructs.

Comment: If you run the codes, will it give you error reports?

Comment: the addition of an `__init__.py` file may be contributing to the problem, as Pylance may see that, and then be expecting relative imports within the apparent package.

Comment: Please post a solution as an answer, not by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've chosen [the workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_start-vs-code-in-a-workspace-folder).

If it doesn't work, you can try adding the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE"
  ],
```