# Visual Studio Code Terminal Error, Unable to Run the code. Terminal is failing to Launch

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" does not exist.

Comment: You could also install "Git for Windows". https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Bash on Windows from the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this issue. We need to go to settings.json file edit it to "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

You can also follow below link : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Below is the screenshot of the same

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your terminal path with following steps:

1. Go to shortcuts-search with `Cntr + Shift + p`
2. Search for `default`
3. Click on `Terminal: Select Default Shell`
4. Select path of your favorite shell available on your system.