# Visual Studio Code C# how can I change the console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding with VSC this semester and I don't know much.

I installed vsc, c# and .net core (not sure if I need anything else).

Since I know very little I followed a Youtube tutorial to learn the basics. Everything worked fine until he wanted to change text color.
I copied every step but I noticed that the debug console is not changing the text color and that the Youtuber was using an external terminal/console (don't know the difference).
I thought who cares about color and just continued with the video. Some code later he wrote an input:

```
// Ask users name
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");

// Get user input
string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
        
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, let's play a game...", inputName); 
// This is never displayed  after giving the debug console a name
```

Copied the input but all I was able to do in the debug console is typing name after name and nothing happens. The program runs forever if I do not close it.
Than I thought the problem was the debug console and I started to google how to change that.
So I googled again and again and was not able to find how to change the console to an external one all things I found were not helpful to me.

Long story short. How can I change the terminal or console form not using the debug console so I can change the text color and so on?

Thanks in advance Jona

Comment: Add `Console.ReadLine();` to the end of your code

Comment: This may answer your question: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal&ved=2ahUKEwjpluyq0a_uAhWOXM0KHawFAUwQFjABegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw0iK9s2CpjHN8Ulzn8z6_3U.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANSI escape codes within your output message:

```
Console.WriteLine("\x1b[32mThis text is green\x1b[0m");
```

will output `This text is green` in green foreground color. You can search for other color codes if you'd like to have another color. You can also change the background color if you wish:

```
Console.WriteLine("\x1b[48;5;43mThis text has a yellow background\x1b[0m");
```

Warning: this will change the color in terminal emulators only. In environments such as Docker you will see those escape codes as part of your logs, such as `\x1b[32mThis text is green\x1b[0m`, instead of colors (I haven't tested this), which is probably not something you'd want.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your code to change color. Replace Blue if you like some other colors.

`Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;`

Comment: Thanks but the debug console will not change its color, that s why I am looking for help how to get an external console