# Set git bash as default terminal in VSCODE

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have git installed in my D: but my VSCODE is in C: and when I try to set Git bash as default it dont show to me. What should I do ?

Comment: Hint: `%PATH%`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159674/7976758

Answer (score 1):

@Francisco Lucca,
I hope the answer to your question could be found in the below link.

[How do I use Bash on Windows from the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal)

Checkout the second answer.

Comment: Please go through the comments of the second answer as well