# 'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on windows npm script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, visual-studio-code, eval

```
$ npm run deploy:local

> backend@0.1.0 deploy:local
> eval "`aws-auth-helper ` lerna run deploy:sandbox --stream"

'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Node version:

```
$ node --version
v15.11.0
```

NPM version:

```
$ npm --version
7.6.0
```

I am using VSCode Bash terminal. It had been working just fine but then I started getting this error. Have tried both bash terminal and javascript terminal.

If I just type "eval" in the bash terminal, it works okay. While running through npm script it does not.

Comment: Seems like you are using a command designed for bash inside batch/cmd. There is a huge difference between linux' bash and windows' batch. Please make sure that you are actually using the latter.

Comment: @Socowi I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527994/2699001 . Do I need to switch to something else?

Comment: I have no idea. In windows there is no pre-installed bash. Therefore I don't know if you even can *switch* to bash. You might have to install WSL, git-bash, cygwin or something like that first.

Comment: It is infact git-bash that is currently being used and I am under the impression that it used to work just fine as is

Comment: `is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` is cmd's message when it encounters an unknown command. I don't know node.js but you either write a cmd command, or change node.js' default shell somehow, or call bash from cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on a Windows environment, even if the *shell* you're executing from is bash, `npm` will likely be executing the run script in the default shell of Windows (PS now, I think?).

You could try modifying your *package.json* file in this way

Note that if `bash` is not in your `PATH`, you'll have to use the full path

```json
{
//... other keys
  "scripts" : {
    //... other keys
    "deploy" : "bash -c \"eval `aws-auth-helper ` lerna run deploy:sandbox --stream\" "
  }
}
```