# VSCode Configuring Default Integrated Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VScode so sorry if this is a silly question.

I am trying to configure VS-code to use command prompt instead of powershell while running/debugging. I tried the instructions at: [The new way to configure default shell and argument commands in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601161/the-new-way-to-configure-default-shell-and-argument-commands-in-vscode) but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have added

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
```

to the bottom of my settings.json file. However when I try to run a python file it still runs it in powershell:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is known bug and it will be fixed in the next version 1.60.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode is suddenly defaulting to powershell for integrated terminal and tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047142/vscode-is-suddenly-defaulting-to-powershell-for-integrated-terminal-and-tasks)

Comment: @Timothy G. and adam, Yes this answers my question. Thanks!