# New way to specify Powershell 7 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to replace the default Powershell 5 with the newer Powershell 7, on Windows 11.

99% of the solutions on the internet say to add this to `settings.json`.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe"
```

However, this now gives a red squiggly line with the following message:

> This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default
> shell is by creating a terminal profile in
> `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name
> as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`. This
> will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that
> will change in the future.(2)

There is one [possibly related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601161/the-new-way-to-configure-default-shell-and-argument-commands-in-vscode), but it only deals with defaulting it to the native `Command Prompt`, rather than re-jigging things to `Powershell 7`.

So, what is the correct new way to provide `Powershell 7`s path to VS Code, and also set it as the default terminal?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Preface**:

- The solution below addresses the question as asked, involving modification of the `settings.json` file.
- However, there is now a *GUI* method available that allows you to pick the default profile more conveniently, assuming that your [PowerShell 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) installation is in a standard location known to Visual Studio Code - see [Lee Grissom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77971795/45375).
  For installations not auto-discoverable by Visual Studio Code or for customizing the startup options of existing profiles you'll still need the `settings.json` method, however.
- Both methods relate to use of PowerShell 7 as the default *general-purpose* shell in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.

  - By contrast, if you have the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed (for authoring and debugging PowerShell code) and want to control what edition / version is being used in its special-purpose shell, the PIC (PowerShell-Integrated Console), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375).

---

In *earlier* VSCode (Visual Studio Code) versions, the `"terminal.integrated.shell.*"` and `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.*"` settings determined the default shell and its startup arguments for the integrated terminal.

These have been superseded by [shell *profiles*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles), defined via `"terminal.integrated.profiles.*"` properties and an associated `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.*"` property that contains the *name* of the profile to use *by default*, as shown below.

```json
// Excerpt from settings.json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell_7": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },  // ...
}

// Make the profile defined above the default profile.
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell_7"
```

Note:

- Open your `settings.json` file for editing as follows: From the command palette (select menu command `View` > `Command Palette...` or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>), select command `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`; searching for `user json` should be enough to locate it.
- I would have expected Visual Studio Code to use your v7 version *automatically*, as it - if installed - normally takes precedence over Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Just installing powershell extension updated vscode to use pwsh 7.3.3 instead of powershell 5.1! Thanks!

Comment: by default in VS Code, to open the Preferences Open Settings (JSON), in VS Code, use CTRL + SHIFT + P then type 'settings json'

Comment: Thanks, @JohnYoungtree - I've added a note to that effect to the answer (along with a preface).

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_windows-powershell

> When PowerShell 6+ is installed, Windows PowerShell is not included in the profiles list by default. To add Windows PowerShell as a profile, choose the Select Default Profile option in the new terminal dropdown and select the Windows PowerShell item. This will configure the profile and set it as your default.

[image: Select Default Profile Menu Item]
[image: Select PowerShell exe]