# VS Code with PowerShell 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed PowerShell 7 and attempting to use it in VS Code. However, after opening a ps1 module and running it; VS Code always switches to PowerShell Extension and attempts to run it using v5.1.

How do I force VS Code to use PowerShell v7?

Thank you,
Bob

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73845252/new-way-to-specify-powershell-7-in-visual-studio-code