# Git Bash is not showing on Visual Studio Code, altroalthough I installed

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with Git bash. In my computer I installed `git bash`. But I can not take this app into Vs Code Terminal. I tried a lot of variants.

[image]

My `setting.json`

```
    "Git Bash": {
      "path": "D:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
  }
```

I also tried to fix into
My Computer>Properties>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables>Path>
[image]

My git version `git version 2.39.2.windows.1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068359/gitbash-not-showing-up-as-a-terminal-option-in-visual-studio-code)
You need to set `source` OR  `path`.

Comment: @Talkhak1313 I also set source and path here. But it does not work. I dont know what is my mistake

Comment: You must set `source` OR `path`, not both.

Comment: *@Rahil* You may remove the `source` and see how it goes.