# Work on ReactJS that was developed on Linux/Mac on Windows

Tags: reactjs, linux, windows, macos

I have experience developing **ReactJS** apps on **Windows** (with VSCode and Git/Sourcetree), but I have never used Linux/Mac.

Now I'm going to work (temporarily) with a team who are working on a huge/mature ReactJS project. The problem is they're all on **Linux** and **Mac** (they use Git too).

I am hoping to be able to just use my Sourcetree and VSCode and everything on **Windows**, but I imagine at least the `scripts` in their `package.json` won't easily run on my Windows machine?

If anyone has faced a similar situation I would really appreciate some advice so I could prepare.

Comment: Many `scripts` work just fine. See how it goes first before worrying in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work on a project developed on Linux, and make Linux commands from the package.json scripts run on Visual Studio Code on Windows:

1. Install [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)
2. [Set VSCode to use Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal)
3. Run this command to make npm scripts run in Bash:

   ```
   npm config set script-shell 
   "C:\Users\hardi.sempuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe"
   ```

   (To undo this: `npm config delete script-shell`)