# How to solve cargo build-bpf not working?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, solana

I am trying to build a Rust project and when I try to execute `cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=contracts/solana/program/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/solana/program` in the terminal I got this error:

> Can't get home directory path: environment variable not found

Any ideas about how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cargo build-bpf` requires the `HOME` environment variable to be set to work. To resolve this, you have a few options:

- Switch VS Code to use a Bash-supported shell.  This will be your easiest option, and then `HOME` will always be set.  More information about how to do that at: [How do I use Bash on Windows from the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal)
- Set the `HOME` variable yourself in Powershell, using something like:

```
$Env:Home = "c:\path\to\my\work\dir"
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that the second option will work.

More information about the specific error you're seeing at the `cargo-build-bpf` source code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d5dec989b93fc94c9416a60193e52e8b68bd7133/sdk/cargo-build-bpf/src/main.rs#L474

Comment: @MirciaGeorge Then you should accept the answer Jon has given you so others can find it and know it worked

Comment: Try from bash terminal