# Use of ls -la on windows OS

Tags: powershell, command-line, ls

software devs it is requested to help me. I want to use the ls -la command on the vs code terminal. It is not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyAvv.png)

I tried setting the execution policy to unrestricted. It got unrestricted but it still didn't work. Look i have used ls -la command on a kali linux vm in the past. Currently i am trying to usxe it on a windows default os running vs code and it isn't working. Please help me. Regards

Comment: I feel your pain. Windows remains the last major commonly used operating system that is not Unix based. You'd be much happier using MacOS if you're used to Linux. However, there are ways to run Unix commands in Windows. You can for example run WSL under vscode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl. Alternatively you can also set up vscode to use gitbash (a version of bash that runs on Windows): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+%22ls+-la%22

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is a unix command. The equivalent for that in windows is `dir`.
If you still want to use 'ls', better of setting it as an alias for `dir`.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -la` is a linux command that displays all the files including hidden files in long format. The equivalent of it on Windows is `dir /a`