In VS Code at ''dotnet run" in bash terminal giving error while in integrated dotnet terminal no error
Big Main Screen
no error screen
error screen
Tried all what were diagnosed ..invain  error
tried dotnet run <prog name>.dll
dotnet run <progname>
happening same in dotnet integrated terminal its runs good but not in bash terminal

error Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in C:\Users

tried to upload image of screen shots but not being uploaded to stack overflow


Open Vs Code.

Press CTRL + SHIFT + P
It will Open Command Palette

Here write defaultSettings.json.

Click on it. Opens file

Press CTRL + F to enter into search Bar.

Here Write bash.exe, it will highlight all related Configurations,
More of them commented out in (green color) One will be sky blue color looking bright

That what is currently enabled.

Profile with non double forward slash is now active, else have // which are non functional commented out.
here what it will looks like---Last one is active
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": null,


which means automatically detect the defaults, Select which path of file you want to choose Eg. path: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe  Enable it by removing forward slash [//] in front of it, rest keep in // now that profile will be active
I hope that works for you..
 // The default terminal profile on Windows.
//  - null: Automatically detect the default
//  - PowerShell: $(terminal-powershell) PowerShell
// - path: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
//  - Windows PowerShell: $(terminal-powershell) Windows PowerShell
// - path: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
//  - Git Bash: $(terminal) Git Bash
// - path: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
// - args: ['--login','-i']
//  - Command Prompt: $(terminal-cmd) Command Prompt
// - path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
// - args: []
//  - JavaScript Debug Terminal: $($(debug)) JavaScript Debug Terminal
// - extensionIdentifier: ms-vscode.js-debug
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": null,


Relevent Stackoverflow Post link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal?rq=2
