# How to split the Git Bash into more than one “view” in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, git-bash

I want to run two commands at the same time in `Git Bash`.

- webpack -w
- node server.js

---

So i want to split my terminal into two or multiple tabs.

How to split the terminal into multiple views ?

Comment: Opening another terminal window/tab is not a valid option for you?

Comment: check out ConEmu. you may need admin rights to install. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202269/set-up-git-bash-to-work-with-tabs-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up git bash to work with tabs on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202269/set-up-git-bash-to-work-with-tabs-on-windows)

Answer (score 10):

Your requirements are:

- Use `git bash`
- Split into 2 or more tabs

You can archive this the following way.

1. Download `Visual Studio Code`
2. Change your integrated terminal to `git bash`. 
   ["terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows)
3. Open a new terminal by clicking on `Terminal` > `new Terminal` in VS Code top navigation bar.
4. [Split your terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-splitting)

Comment: If the git bash exe file is not located in this default place you can find its location by running
`git --exec-path`.

Answer (score 6):

Git Bash, won't allow users to split the screen in to two as the features don't exist. The only way is to use alternative or use ConEmu to configure, my personal preference would be Cmder (console emulator) and other options would be Moba Xterm. Cmder is open source and completely free. This would be much easier than configuring ConEmu.

- Cmder: http://cmder.net/
- MobaXterm: https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

Answer (score 3):

Launch two instances of GIT Bash and press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to automatically divide the screen into two halves and select desired programs.

Comment: Game changer D:

Answer (score 3):

To duplicate a GIT bash in windows press Alt + F2.

This opens a new terminal in the same path as the previous.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in `Windows Terminal`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal

`Windows Terminal Preview` can be configured to save your panes layout on close:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n8g5rfz9xk3

See this post for how to add a `Git Bash` profile automatically:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69093260

Other features include:

- Set starting directory for `Git Bash` profile and `Defaults`
- Customise pane theme, colors, fonts, background images ([including animated gifs](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/adding-reaction-gifs-for-your-build-system-and-the-windows-terminal)), transparency, cursor shape, 'retro terminal effects' etc