# Adding Git-Bash to the new Windows Terminal

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I'm trying to add a new terminal (Git Bash) to the new Windows Terminal. However, I can't get it to work.

I tried changing the `commandline` property in the `profiles` array to `git-bash.exe` but no luck.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Explained: http://donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-add-profiles-to-the-new-Windows-Terminal

Comment: Use the Windows Terminal Tweaker to configure the terminal effortlessly : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/windows-terminal-tweaker

Comment: Would this question be better off at superuser instead of Stack Overflow?

Comment: **Note:** _TortoiseGit_ installer will now do this for you

Answer (score 822, accepted):

## Overview

1. Open settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. You'll want to append one of the profiles options below (depending on what version of git you have installed) to the `"list":` portion of the `settings.json` file:

[image: Open settings.json in Windows Terminal sidebar]

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

    "defaultProfile": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000001}",

    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles
        },
        "list":
        [
            <put one of the configuration below right here>
        ]
    }
}
```

### Profile options

Uncomment correct paths for `commandline` and `icon` if you are using:

- Git for Windows in `%PROGRAMFILES%`
- Git for Windows in `%USERPROFILE%`
- If you're using [scoop](https://scoop.sh/)

```json
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
    "commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/bin/bash.exe -i -l",
    // "commandline": "%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/bin/bash.exe -l -i",
    // "commandline": "%USERPROFILE%/scoop/apps/git/current/usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i",
    "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
    // "icon": "%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
    // "icon": "%USERPROFILE%/scoop/apps/git/current/usr/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
    "name" : "Bash",
    "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%"
},
```

You can also add other options like:

```json
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
    // ...
    "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
    "closeOnExit" : true,
    "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
    "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
    "cursorShape" : "bar",
    "fontFace" : "Consolas",
    "fontSize" : 10,
    "historySize" : 9001,
    "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
    "snapOnInput" : true,
    "useAcrylic" : true
}
```

## Notes

- make your own `guid` as of https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/2475 this is no longer generated.
- the `guid` can be used in in the `globals` > `defaultProfile` so you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
  or start a Windows terminal and it will start up bash by default

```
"defaultProfile" : "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000001}",
```

- `-l -i` to make sure that `.bash_profile` gets loaded
- use environment variables so they can map to different systems correctly.
- target `git/bin/bash.exe` to ensure that the environment gets passed in correctly at the expense that it spawns off an additional process.   If `git/usr/bin/bash.exe` it will work as well, but `git` won't be in your path.

I have my configuration that uses Scoop in https://gist.github.com/trajano/24f4edccd9a997fad8b4de29ea252cc8

Comment: Note that bash.exe is under git\\bin, not directly in the Git directory, unlike git-bash.exe. This tripped me up at first.

Comment: A `guid` is NOT generated for me on save

Comment: if you want to add the correct icon, this is what I set the icon field to: `"icon" : "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico"`

Comment: I actually use a custom icon https://icons8.com/icon/set/console/office but it is a good tip if you want the icon

Comment: I was missing the ` -i -l` options for the bash_profile to be loaded. Thanks.

Comment: And just to add to the comment from @ChrisSandvik, the icon can also be referenced like this: `"icon" : "%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico"`

Comment: Does anyone else have trouble with reverse-i-search (CTRL+R) when doing it like this? It doesn't seem to remember anything i've done. So all i get is from the last "real" git bash session.

Comment: If you install git just for your user, the relevant paths are:
`"commandline" : "\"%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Programs\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe\" -i -l"` and `"icon" : "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico"`

Comment: Do you know how to set it for xterm-256color support?  Setup as above, $TERM is cygwin, and only supports 8 color in Windows Terminal.  Using the mintty shell, I have it set to xterm-256color and have full 24-bit color support.  I'd like to have the same capabilities in Git Bash via Windows Terminal.

Comment: During installation If you select Use Git from Git Bash Only in Adjusting your PATH environment, this json configuration won't work. You should select from the other two options.

Comment: I followed the link but didn't see how to generate a guid.

Comment: make up your own, I made up my own just have to follow the pattern

Comment: @neves Open Powershell and run `new-guid`, it'll spit out a fresh one for you.

Comment: Something to note is that I have run into issues using `Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`. It seems that the one in the `usr` folder is missing some environment variables. In my case, I was having issues with `git-upload-pack`, required for the deploy command for [`gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) on NPM. Instead, using `Git\bin\bash.exe` fixed all my `$PATH` related issues.

Comment: Note: Just don't use `git\\git-bash.exe` instead use `bash.exe` in `git\\bin` folder. Otherwise `git-bash` will be opened by its own in a separate window. `"commandline":"%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\bin\\bash.exe", "icon" :"%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico"`

Comment: I don't understand, it doesn't show up in the list, but everything is right :/

Comment: The guid in the settings needs braces around it - the default output from PowerShell's `New-Guid` cmdlet omits them. You can use `(New-Guid).ToString("b") | scb` to copy a fresh guid to the clipboard in the correct format.

Comment: "..\\git\\bin\\bash.exe" is available on Windows.

Comment: My git-bash was installed into AppData\Local so my commandline is C:\\Users\\<USERNAME>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe -l -i

Comment: Configured as described and everything appears to work great, however, when opening a new Git Bash tab in Windows Terminal, I get an output of `bash: [!: command not found    bash: [2: command not found    bash: []: command not found`.  Has anyone else observed this? All Git commands work as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to set environment variables in the Windows Terminal? Namely I want to open `cmd` or `git-bash` with some pre defined system variables.

Answer (score 144):

There are below things to do.

1. Make sure the `git` command runs successfully in Command Prompt.

That means you need to add `git` to path when install git or add it to system environment later.

[image: Run git in Command Prompt]

2. Update the file `profile.json`: open `Settings` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> in Windows Terminal, click on Open JSON file in the sidebar, and add following snippet inside the word `profiles`:

[image: Open settings.json in Windows Terminal sidebar]

```sh
        { 
            "tabTitle": "Git Bash",
            "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75, 
            "closeOnExit" : true, 
            "colorScheme" : "Campbell", 
            "commandline" : "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe --login", 
            "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF", 
            "cursorShape" : "bar", 
            "fontFace" : "Consolas", 
            "fontSize" : 12, 
            "guid" : "{14ad203f-52cc-4110-90d6-d96e0f41b64d}", 
            "historySize" : 9001, 
            "icon": "ms-appdata:///roaming/git-bash_32px.ico",
            "name" : "Git Bash", 
            "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0", 
            "snapOnInput" : true, 
            "useAcrylic" : true 
        }
```

The icon can be obtained here: [git-bash_32px.ico](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yanglr/WindowsDevTools/master/awosomeTerminal/icons/git-bash_32px.ico)

You can add icons for Tab to this location:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\RoamingState`

Put 32x32 PNG/icons in this folder, and then in `profile.json` you can reference the image resource with the path starting with `ms-appdata://`.

Note that, please make sure the `Guid`is correct and it matches the corresponding correct configurations.

3. Test that git bash works in Windows Terminal.

The final result is below:
[image]

Comment: @Mendy FYI, wish it be helpful for you.

Comment: You can also get the icon from 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico'

Comment: Is there a way to not have it go straight into /c/windows/system32?

Comment: Thank you... the marked answer didn't work for me for some reason but this one did. I have my git installed on a different partition so the environment variables were an issue. This answer has less info but is much straight forward on achieving the goal.

Comment: The bash was always opening in a new window for me. I fixed it changing the path from `git-bash.exe` to `bin\bash.exe`

Comment: @Brooklyn add this line: `"startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%"`

Comment: Hi I found the icon but in the second step, 'settings' do you mean the setting on my laptop or something else? and I can't find 'profiles' file....

Comment: @Cecilia, settings here means the "Settings" in dropdown list of Windows Terminal (see last screenshot in this answer.)

Comment: @BravoYeung Hi I don't see 'Settings', if I click on the left top corner for my windows cmd, it only have 'Properties' / ''Defaults'/'Edit' etc, am I looking at the wrong terminal?

Comment: @Cecilia Hi, this topic we discussed in this question is Microsoft's new windows terminal (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701), you used is just the traditional one. So they have different GUI. If you want to open git in the traditional one, you only need to complete step 1 in this answer.

Comment: Hi @BravoYeung Thanks, do you mean I only need to add git bash path to my environment path? Is this the right path? `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`? Or `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe (I also have bash.exe/sh.exe under bin folder)`, when I navigate to my environment variables, I found that I already have 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd' do I need all of them?

Answer (score 118):

This is the complete answer (**GitBash + color scheme + icon + context menu**)

1. Set default profile:

```json
"globals": 
{
    "defaultProfile" : "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
    ...
```

2. Add GitBash profile

```json
"profiles": [
    {
        "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
        "acrylicOpacity": 0.75,
        "closeOnExit": true,
        "colorScheme": "GitBash",
        "commandline": "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" --login -i",
        "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "cursorShape": "bar",
        "fontFace": "Consolas",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "historySize": 9001,
        "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
        "name": "GitBash",
        "padding": "0, 0, 0, 0",
        "snapOnInput": true,
        "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
        "useAcrylic": false
    }
]
```

3. Add GitBash color scheme

```json
  "schemes": [
      {
          "background": "#000000",
          "black": "#0C0C0C",
          "blue": "#6060ff",
          "brightBlack": "#767676",
          "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
          "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
          "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
          "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
          "brightRed": "#E74856",
          "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
          "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
          "cyan": "#3A96DD",
          "foreground": "#bfbfbf",
          "green": "#00a400",
          "name": "GitBash",
          "purple": "#bf00bf",
          "red": "#bf0000",
          "white": "#ffffff",
          "yellow": "#bfbf00",
          "grey": "#bfbfbf"
      }
  ]
```

4. To add a right-click context menu "Windows Terminal Here"

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\wt]
@="Windows terminal here"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\{YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\{YOUR_ICONS_FOLDER}\\icon.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\wt\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\{YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe\""
```

- Replace `{YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME}` with your Windows username.
- Create an icon folder, put the icon there and replace `{YOUR_ICONS_FOLDER}` with your icon folder.
- Save this in a `.reg` file and run it.

Comment: Why do you use the MSYS version `Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe` instead of Git for Windows's default MINGW version `Git\\bin\\bash.exe`?

Comment: @KeithRussell I don't know much of the differences but I use what works for me. I think I had installed GitBash for windows to be able to run shell scripts etc. 
By the way after writing this reply I found a much more comfortable setup so I'm not using the new windows terminal anymore. I'm currently using Atom editor with an integrated command line using the `atom-ide-terminal` package from Qicrosoft with `Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe`. Is there any obvious advantage for using `Git\\bin\\bash.exe`?

Comment: From my experience with MSYS and MinGW in 2015, and my experience with MinGW Git-Bash over this past year, I’d expect most programs run under MSYS Git-Bash to behave the same as under MinGW Git-Bash, but run significantly slower. But I’ve never tried MSYS Git-Bash.

Comment: @KeithRussell I haven't really noticed any slow time but if I do later, I may test between them.

Comment: Sweet! Simply copied and pasted. Icons work, colors work, perfect.

Comment: @KeithRussell I investigated and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/56844443/8874388, and can confirm what it says. `bin\bash.exe` is a tiny 43kb launcher for `usr\bin\bash.exe` (2 mb). Basically like a symlink, just for convenience (the `bin` folder contains bash, sh and git). In other words, there is no difference. I am not sure why they bothered to make the `bin` folder version at all. Perhaps for legacy `PATH` variable reasons (to not infect the path with ls.exe, cat.exe etc too). But yeah, we should be using `usr/bin/bash.exe` to avoid the pointless `bin/bash.exe` wrapper.

Comment: @MitchMcMabers I’m surprised, because my understanding is as recently as five years ago, MSYS and MinGW were different environments. MinGW was basically some programs you could run from a Windows environment, and MSYS was actual (stripped-down) POSIX emulation. And when we experimented with both, we found MSYS was *way* slower for the same operations. (But preferable because you actually had POSIX.)

Comment: @KeithRussell I am surprised too, because they clearly started out as different things. I did research yesterday and was not able to get a clear understanding of what their relationship is. From what I read, it seems like MinGW and MSYS2 are related to each other these days, but don't quote me on that, because the material I was reading was far from crystal-clear. ;-) That being said, I was able to reproduce the results: Go to Windows Task Manager - Details Tab, start `Git\bin\bash.exe` and you will see 2 `bash.exe` spawn, the latter being `Git\usr\bin\bash.exe` which is launched by the prior.

Comment: @KeithRussell Also, if you right click the column header in the Windows Task Manager - Details tab, and Select columns, and enable the "Command line" column, you can see that `Git\usr\bin\bash.exe` is started without any extra arguments. So the only potential thing that the `Git\bin\bash.exe` wrapper does is inject environment variables before launching, but I think the only thing it injects is the `$MSYSTEM = MINGW64` variable which causes the PS1 prompt to have a different title, but I doubt it injects anything else, since everything works properly when launching either of the binaries.

Comment: Also note that `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe` does not behave properly (cannot find built-in commands, does not have MSYS title in PS1 prompt) if launched directly, such as via Win+R or via cmd.exe, etc, but it works perfectly if launched via a Terminal host such as the brand new Microsoft Windows Terminal, or the community-project "Alacritty", etc. I am running it through Microsoft Windows Terminal (a kickass new open source project by Microsoft, which provides a fast, GPU-accelerated terminal that can host any shell; I'm using it with Bash + PowerShell 6 + cmd). :-)

Comment: Due to change in `settings.json` in latest version. Step should be more look like following:

```
    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
        },
        "list":
        [
   {
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}",
                 ...
                 ...
```

Comment: If anyone's unable to open the terminal in the working dir, replace the address in the last line with:

`"C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" -d .`

Comment: I would add: "suppressApplicationTitle": true to enforce the use of "tabTitle": "GitBash"  in settings.json for the GitBash profile. This will ensure that the shell can't override the title that has been set in the config-file. Figured this out when I suddenly got the current path as the title.

Comment: @Corepuncher that's the goal always, copy-paste solution, to save people's time :)

Comment: Just pointing out that you do not have to specify the `-l` flag, as this is the same as `--login`. So it should read: `"commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe --login -i"`

Comment: If you like to be able to see it you can change the `"acrylicOpacity": 0.75,` line to a more reasonable setting

Answer (score 110):

It's **Sept 2021**, thankfully the latest [Git Installation installer for Windows](https://git-scm.com/) (mine was using 2.33.0.2) already has this option covered for us, for the sake of our laziness (and convenience, of course!)

**Please install the Windows Terminal first before installing Git**, although I haven't try the otherway around, but better follow the sensible order. If the installation order is not the case, please let me know to update this answer.

You may find this handful checkbox at the bottom within the installation stage **Select Components**, just tick the box there and you're good to go.
[image]

The `settings.json` file will be added the Git Bash profile automatically with correct Git Bash icon. My generated Git Bash profile is pretty standard and minimal.

```
{
    "guid": "{2ece5bfe-50ed-5f3a-ab87-5cd4baafed2b}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "source": "Git"
}
```

If Windows Terminal is running, close and launch again for the Git Bash option to be visible.

Comment: This is the best current answer.

Answer (score 61):

Because most answers either show a lot of unrelated configuration or don't show the configuration, I created my own answer that tries to be more focused. It is mainly based on the [profile settings reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings) and [Archimedes Trajano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57369284/4967497).

## Steps

1. Open *PowerShell* and enter `[guid]::NewGuid()` to generate a new GUID. We will use it at step 3.

   ```
   > [guid]::NewGuid()

   Guid
   ----
   a3da8d92-2f3f-4e36-9714-98876b6cb480
   ```
2. Open the settings of *Windows Terminal*. (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
3. Add the following JSON object to `profiles.list`. Replace `guid` with the one you generated at step 1.

   ```json
   {
     "guid": "{a3da8d92-2f3f-4e36-9714-98876b6cb480}",
     "name": "Git Bash",
     "commandline": "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" -i -l",
     "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
     "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%"
   },
   ```

## Notes

- There is currently an issue that you cannot use your arrow keys (and some other keys). It seems to work with the latest preview version, though. ([issue #6859](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6859))
- Specifying `"startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%"` shouldn't be necessary [according to the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#starting-directory). However, if I don't specify it, the starting directory was different depending on how I started the terminal initially.
- Settings that shall apply to all terminals can be specified in `profiles.defaults`.
- I recommend to set `"antialiasingMode": "cleartype"` in `profiles.defaults`. You have to remove `"useAcrylic"` (if you have added it as suggested by some other answers) to make it work. It improves the quality of text rendering. However, you cannot have transparent background without `useAcrylic`. See [issue #1298](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1298).
- If you have problems with the cursor, you can try another shape like `"cursorShape": "filledBox"`. See [cursor settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#cursor-settings) for more information.

Comment: thank you for writing about `NewGuid()`, going to add a link on MS learn for [git-bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles#git-bash) settings the way they see it

Answer (score 36):

That's how I've added mine in profiles json table,

```json
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
    "name": "Git",
    "commandline": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe --login",
    "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
    "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
    "hidden": false
}
```

Comment: This is short and the best answer here!

Comment: I needed to generate a new Guid first (open powershell > [guid]::NewGuid() ) and use it instead of the one above! But except this its works fine :)

Answer (score 20):

In case anyone is looking for a UI-Based solution. Here it is:

1. Go to the Terminal's settings.
2. At the Right buttom side, look for the "Add new profile" option.
   [Screenshot for the Terminal's settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEGhR.png)
3. Select "New Empty Profile"
4. Now complete the fields with the information about your bash. If your installation locations are the default ones, you could use these:

- **Name:** Git-Bash
- **Command line**: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
- **Startin directory**: *[Leave as default]*
- **Icon**: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico
- **Tab title**: Git-Bash
  [Temrinal Settings completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAlDT.png)
  You could also browse for the right files in case you need to.

5. Hit Save button.

**Final Result**

[Final Result. Bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Rse.png)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Way simpler than other solutions!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very simple and straightforward

Answer (score 14):

Change the profiles parameter to `"commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe -l -i"`

This works for me and allows for my .bash_profile alias autocomplete scripts to run.

Answer (score 14):

Another item to note - in settings.json
I discovered if you don't use
"commandline": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe"

and instead use:
"commandline": "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe"

the Git shell will open up in an independent window outside of Windows Terminal instead of on a tab - which is not the desired behavior.
In addition, the tab in Windows Terminal that opens will also need to be closed manually as it will display process exited information - [process exited with code 3221225786] etc.

Might save someone some headache

Comment: How do I solve this? I want to "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe"

Comment: I did not use git-bash.exe because of the issues so I cannot assist, unfortunately.

Comment: This is something I came across, guys if you are used to use "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe", you will have to start using "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe". The "\usr\bin" although looks like a Linux one is still there, even though you are on Windows.

Comment: Use C:\Program Files\Git\bash.exe to open in another tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The new version of windows terminal can be configured through its GUI.

```
Setting -> Add new
Under "command line" add the path -> path/to/Git/bin/bash.exe
```

Comment: Most answers are correct here. This was the quickest one.
Also don't forget to add bash icon and starting directory.

Answer (score 7):

As of Git For Windows `2.42.0` or later, which came out in Aug. 2023 I believe, you can now just re-run the installer and check the box for `(NEW!) Add a Git Bash Profile to Windows Terminal`, as shown in blue here in the `Git 2.42.0` setup:

[image]

That's it!

I first documented that in my instructions here: for other recommended settings to choose while installing Git for Windows, see my personal installation instructions here: **[Installing Git For Windows](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/issues/27#issue-1950880578)**.

### Going further

1. If `echo ~` doesn't show your proper HOME directory in Git Bash, see my instructions here to fix it: [Change the location of the `~` [Home] directory in a Windows install of Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77450145/4561887).
2. If you ever need to build with `gcc`/`g++` or `clang` in Windows, use the MSYS2 terminals instead.

   See my MSYS2 setup answer here: [Installing & setting up MSYS2 from scratch, including adding all 7 profiles to Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887)

Comment: Awsome.  I am installing Git for windows right now and I've been searching everywhere to figure out what exactly that option does.  But your link is not going to git instructions.  It's going to some wierd page.

Comment: @Sam, link updated.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to display an icon and are using a dark theme. Which means the icon provided above doesn't look that great. Then you can find the icon here

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows` I copied it into.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\RoamingState
```

and named it `git-bash_32px` as suggested above.

Control the opacity with CTRL + SHIFT + scrolling.

```
        {
            "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
            "closeOnExit" : true,
            "colorScheme" : "Campbell",
            "commandline" : "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" -i -l",
            "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
            "cursorShape" : "bar",
            "fontFace" : "Consolas",
            "fontSize" : 10,
            "guid" : "{73225108-7633-47ae-80c1-5d00111ef646}",
            "historySize" : 9001,
            "icon" : "ms-appdata:///roaming/git-bash_32px.ico",
            "name" : "Bash",
            "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
            "snapOnInput" : true,
            "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
            "useAcrylic" : true
        },
```

Answer (score 6):

Now Terminal has the option to add a new profile, without modifying the settings JSON.

Go to "Settings" from the dropdown menu as shown below.

[image]

Under the "Profiles" section in the sidebar, select "Add a new profile". Click on "+New empty profile". The following screen opens up.

[image]

Add the details as shown in the below screen for git bash or any other bash.

[image]

Thats all!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know from my current windows terminal version 1.15.2874.0, you can get what you want with a simple manual click to configure it.
**The prerequisites are**

1. your git bash client is installed.
2. at least windows terminal version 1.15.2874.0 or higher.

Then complete the setup by following these steps.

1. Open windows terminal and find "Settings" in the drop-down list in the top right corner of the menu bar (or use the shortcut ctrl+,);
2. Click on "Add new profile" at the bottom of the left hand column, then the settings template screen will pop up automatically.
3. interactive mouse click you want to set the "name", "executable path command line", "startup directory", "icon" value. For example, I set mine to `"gitBash"`, `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"`, `"%USERPROFILE%"`, and "%USERPROFILE%" in order of customisation. `"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico"`.
4. save.

The following screenshots are for reference.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Linux guy, here, sorry I am late; I am just installing git-bash for the first time and looking into what its command should be in Windows Terminal.

As far as I know

- Cygwin is not Windows, but it provides a POSIX translation layer (`cygwin*.dll`) so that all those non-Windows executables can run. Even when a new computer program is compiled and built with cygwin, it still turns out a non-Windows executable and it still needs `cygwin*.dll` to run.
- MSYS2 is mostly Windows with only a few tools that are probably difficult to port remaining non-Windows and requiring a POSIX translation layer to run (`msys*.dll`); but, most programs are actually Windows native executables. Even when a new computer program is compiled and built, it is my understanding that turns out a Windows native *.exe.

But I still don't know how important it is that some of these `MSYSTEM*` and `MINGW*` environment variables be set or not, when I am going to be using MINGW compiler, anyway.

I did notice that, throughout this thread, both command lines keep showing up, namely, `./bin/bash` and `./usr/bin/bash`; so, I went ahead and launched them to compare their environments...they can turn out rather different.

Let it be known that, PREVIOUS to launching any of the shells below, I already have `C:\Git\mingw64\bin` and `C:\Git\usr\bin` as part of System variable `PATH`; I do this because I want to have the ability to use bash commands directly from CMD.  But I don't think this does anything to the results below.

```
                                        c:\Git\bin\bash.exe --login     c:\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe --login
Environment Variable    c:\Git\bin\bash.exe                     c:\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
EXEPATH                 c:\git\bin      c:\git\bin              n       n
HOSTNAME                n               MDXXXXXX                n       MDXXXXXX
MINGW_CHOST             n               x86_64-w64-mingw32      n       n
MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX    n               mingw-w64-x86_64        n       n
MINGW_PREFIX            n               /mingw64                n       n
MSYSTEM_CARCH           n               x86_64                  n       x86_64
MSYSTEM_CHOST           n               x86_64-w64-mingw32      n       x86_64-pc-msys
MSYSTEM_PREFIX          n               /mingw64                n       /usr
MSYSTEM                 MINGW64         MINGW64                 n       MSYS
PLINK_PROTOCOL          ssh             ssh                     n       n
SHELL                   n               /usr/bin/bash           n       /usr/bin/bash
TMPDIR                  n               /tmp                    n       /tmp

ORIGINAL_PATH           n               y                       n       y
ORIGINAL_TEMP           n               y                       n       y
ORIGINAL_TMP            n               y                       n       y
PATH                    /mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
PATH                                    $HOME/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
PATh                                                            $PATH
PATH                                                                    $HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:$PATH
```

So, for good measure, it looks to me as if the more correct thing would be to use `./bin/bash --login`; but I at this very moment, I am not sure what the difference will be, say, when it comes to actually compiling a brand new program with MINGW64/GCC; we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows:

1. Add "%programfiles%\Git\Bin" to your PATH
2. On the profiles.json, set the desired command-line as "commandline" : "sh --cd-to-home"
3. Restart the Windows Terminal

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe -l -i"` doesn't work for me. Because of space symbol (which is separator in cmd) in %PROGRAMFILES% terminal executes command `"C:\Program"` instead of `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe -l -i"`. The solution should be something like adding quotation marks in json file, but I didn't figure out how. 
The only solution is to add "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" to %PATH% and write `"commandline": "bash.exe"` in profiles.json

Comment: I used  `"commandline" : "C:\\PROGRA~1\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",`. No need to modify my path

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It lauches cmd. But if I type `"C:\\PROGRA~1\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"` in opened terminal window, bash starts.

Comment: you need an extra set of escaped quote marks around the %PROGRAMFILES%. eg: `"commandline" : "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" -i -l"`

Comment: Seems to work fine with forward slashes in configuration while `%PROGRAMFILES%` contains both space and backslashes, like this `"commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/bin/bash.exe -i -l"`

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may suffer from missing bash history:
in already opened git bash, try initiate another bash - that supposed to load your profile if env vars are properly configured

If this is your case, you can automate it by adding following command line on startup:

```
C:\progra~1\git\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -l -i -c /c/progra~1/git/usr/bin/bash.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the bellow code to the setting.json will solve the problem.

If you have checked the add to windows terminal option when installing the git and you can see the git bash option in the "duplicate a profile" options.

It will work as I was also facing a similar problem.

```
{
    "guid": "{2ece5bfe-50ed-5f3a-ab87-5cd4baafed2b}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "source": "Git"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?