# Attaching Git Bash inside Eclipse

Tags: bash, git, eclipse, dock

I would like to have Git Bash inside Eclipse, similar to Windows cmd terminal.
Right click on project - Show in Local Terminal - Git Bash.
Now it opens in a new window.
I have checked the options under Window - Preferences - Terminal - Local Terminal - Git Bash - Edit , but none works.

On another PC Git Bash opens inside Eclipse - see screenshot with this and the settings.

I would appreciate if you can help me to dock/attach Git Bash back into Eclipse.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Git Bash Eclipse]

Comment: The screenshot shows the other PC, right? How does it look like on your PC?

Comment: Yes, indeed. On my PC it looks like second picture above.

Comment: Are you sure you have `sh.exe` and not `git-bash.exe`? Also `-i` for _interactive_ separated by a blank is important (do you get the same with `-i` as first argument?). If it is exactly the same on both PCs, look at the versions.

Comment: yes, it was git-bash.exe ; after I changed to sh.exe it works inside Eclipse.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to specify the path of `sh.exe`, not of `git-bash.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Adding Git-Bash to the new Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839307/adding-git-bash-to-the-new-windows-terminal/57369284#57369284) what you need to use is point to `%PROGRAMFILES%\git\usr\bin\bash.exe` with the command line arguments of  `-i -l`.  Note that you need to expand to the full path as Eclipse does not support `%` expansion.  What I do is to use the *Browse...* dialog and paste the path there and let Windows expand it for you.

The one you are using starts an MSYS console that in turn starts up a shim which in turn starts up the `bash` command above.

By going directly to `%PROGRAMFILES%\git\usr\bin\bash.exe` you save a few MB of memory and one entry in the Task Mananager.

In the following screenshot I am using the Scoop version, since that's what I have installed, but it should work with the standard installer.

[image]

Here's how it looks like.  Note I set invert terminal colors on settings so that the background will be black otherwise my colors would be hard to read.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but the git functionality is lost.  When I choose git/bin/bash.exe it works.  Thank you as well for the information.

Comment: Interesting that you lose the `git` functionality.  I presume you passed in `-i -l` parameters too because that should've given you the functionality by reading the profile and setting the paths correctly.

Comment: I just tried it and it appears to work for me.  Though I have to fix the paths a little bit because I am using Scoop rather than the traditional one.

Comment: I tried again and made sure -i -l  is set up, but it still looses git somewhere on the way.. Maybe there is some other settings to be considered, but I am fine now that I have a solution.  My git is in the AppData/Local... folder.