# How to open git bash from specific folder in windows 11

Tags: git-bash, windows-11

In window 11 when we right click shows different options from windows 10. In windows 10 there is short cut to open current folder in a git bast. So what is short cut to open current folder in git bash in windows 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Navigate to the folder you want to open in Git Bash.
   [image]
2. Navigate inside the I_Want_To_Open_This_Folder_in_Git_Bash folder and "right-click" with your mouse,
   choose "Show more options".[image]
3. Choose "Git Bash Here".[image]
4. Ready. Smash that up-like button if you liked the answer. [image]

Answer (score 6):

open the command prompt anywhere using right click option.

[image: Right click from mouse]

and use given "Down arrow" in cmd prompt.

[image: cmd prompt option with down arrow symbol]

Choose setting
[image: setting]

Add new profile
[image: use add new profile button]

in command line browse git/git-bash.exe location and add it.
[image: browse and add location of git bash]

.....Using the same down arrow, you can open git.

Answer (score 3):

What I've found, [laid out in this video by Code Astra here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmL9BtLMQso), is that Windows 11 offers a drop down to select the terminal profile of your choice, once you have selected Right Click --> Open in Terminal.

Once you have the Terminal open, select the drop down to the right of the Terminal tab. Here you can select your desired Terminal Profile. If your Git Bash Profile is not found here, select Settings.

[Git Bash Terminal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8La9X.png)

In the settings menu, you can choose your default Terminal profile, application, and decide on other various options.

[Git Bash Terminal Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izY0L.png)

Navigate on the left pane to "Add a new profile," and then under Add a new profile, select "+ New empty profile"

Fill the form. Name it Git Bash, then naviagte tot he "Program Files" directory where the git-bash.exe is found, most likely "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" and choose the starting directory.

Now when you right click, Windows will open Git Bash.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: I may be imagining this but I followed these intructions (after trying regedit solutions and failing), and then suddenly it worked as described by Jeremy Caney...

Answer (score 1):

Just three simple steps...

1. Right-click on your required folder.
2. Select Show more options
3. Click on Git Bash Here

Answer (score 1):

1. Start > Terminal.
2. ⌵ > Settings.
3. Click "+ Add a new profile".
4. Click "+ New empty profile".

   ```
    Name: Git Bash

    SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56867460/490748
    SOURCE: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash
    -i    Force the shell to run interactively.
    -l    Make this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login.

    Command line: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe -i -l

    Starting directory:
        [x] Use parent process directory

    Icon: C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
   ```
5. Click "Save".
6. Click "+ New empty profile".
7. Select Duplicate a profile: [Git Bash]
8. Click "Duplicate".

   ```
    Name: Git Bash (Run as administrator)

    Run this profile as Administrator: [On]
   ```
9. Click "Save".