# How to open a new tab in git bash?

Tags: sql, mongodb, git-bash, hyper

I would like to open a new tab for git bash, like how you can open a new tab in hyper, so that MongoDB can run on one side and prompt can be open on one side. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do that, as there are no options for opening a new tab and I can't seem to find my situation online.

Any Help?

Comment: So, Are you using hyper terminal or default terminal? if it's hyper, you need to install a plugin called `hyper-pane`, which allows splitting your terminal for multitasking side by side. And most of the terminal works by pressing `CMD + D` on mac as well as hyper.

Comment: I am using Git Bash @GolamrabbiAzad

Comment: then, you're in trouble! checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842291/how-to-split-the-git-bash-into-more-than-one-view-in-windows/56209068