# git bash on Console - I'm having GUI bugs

Tags: git, tabs, console

I believe this counts as a new question, because of the strange bug I'm having. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202269/set-up-git-bash-to-work-with-tabs-on-windows) post, which doesn't apply to my issue.

I'm trying out [Console](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), mostly just to unclutter my taskbar. I'd like to add the git bash to Console.

I do what the internet says. I go to Console's settings and add a new tab with the following:

- Title: Git Bash
- Icon: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico
- Shell: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
- Startup dir: the path to your git repo

Well when I click on a new tab for "Git Bash", Console freezes for a second, and then turns into this mess:

[image: The buggyness after I try to open a git bash tab.]

As you can see, this isn't what's expected. There's this tiny, unresizeable window on the top left, which seems to be the regular Console program. And then there's the actual terminal window detached from the tiny Console program window.

In the taskbar, I have the Console icon focused. The icon below corresponds to the detached terminal window.

I can go into more detail about the strange behavior if needed. I don't have my shell exactly set up as mentioned before. I actually have: 
"C:\programming_path\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

I've tried many different combinations, and nothing seems to work.

EDIT: I tried out [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), and it seems miles ahead of Console. I'm just gonna stick with ConEmu instead. I recommend anyone else to check it out if they're having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `bash.exe` is used, no `sh.exe`.
See for instance [ConEmu issue 1355](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1355), with a command like:

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & "%ConEmuDir%\..\Git\git-cmd.exe" --no-cd \
--command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:p
```

Comment: Using Git/bin/bash.exe does the same thing as Git/bin/sh.exe.

Comment: @g8tr1522 Are you using ConEmu when you are talking about "Console"? And did you set the path and use the same option than the one I describe in my answer?

Comment: Ah, no. I'm using the program "Console" or "Console 2" I guess. I wish it had a more distinctive name.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: Well I tried out ConEmu, and it looks way better than Console, so I'm just gonna give up on Console.

Comment: I've been having this problem sporadically on certain machines: my desktop (windows 10 enterprise) is fine with console 2; my work laptop (windows 10 pro) does the exact behavior described above; my brand new laptop (windows 10 pro) also exhibits the behavior. I'm sick of trying to fix it. ConEmu seems better. Thanks for the tip.